# iOS causing overflow-x issue in Shopify - iframe is wider than viewport

Tags: html, css, shopify, embed

I have an issue with an Iframe I am using in Shopify. I have set the width to wider than the viewport to fix an aspect ratio issue, making it about 80% of the height of the screen on mobile. This issue is for IOS specifically. It is a widescreen video, so this was my "fix" to get it to display on mobile with a flipped aspect ratio.

You have to access the site on mobile for the scrolling issue to appear. When I was initially testing the site for mobile release, there were zero scrolling issues on the chrome responsive preview function. I have tried:

Adding:

- overflow: hidden !important
- overflow-x: hidden !important

To:

- html, body
- the iframe inline
- every single container within the html inline

I tried putting a div around the entire container with those properties
I tried using iframe commands like scroll="no" and overflow: hidden based on other posts here. I think most of the issue is the absolute positioning, but I am not experienced enough in CSS to figure out a way around it while still keeping the same display with the video.

I tried to put the code together as best I could in the code editor, but it will really only work if you guys go to the actual site to see the live video.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.vimeo-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 72vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.vimeo-wrapper-content,
.vimeo-wrapper-content-bottom {
  z-index: 2;

}

.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hbtn {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 38px;
  margin: 20px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}



.hb-fill-right::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}



.vimeo-wrapper-content-bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.3);
  display: flex;
}

.hbtn-vimeo {
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-self: center; */
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden !important; overflow-x: hidden !important">
          <div class="vimeo-wrapper-content-bottom" style="overflow: hidden !important; overflow-x: hidden !important">
            <a href="https://www.luckyleodancewear.com/collections/video-lookbook" class="hbtn-vimeo hb-fill-right">Shop the video<i style="padding-left: 5px;" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.luckyleodancewear.com/blogs/luckyleodancewear/behind-the-scenes-of-reflection" class="hbtn-vimeo hb-fill-right">Keep watching<i style="padding-left: 5px;" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/354737357?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0" scroll="no" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to completely re-do the code. I kept absolute on the iframe but put relative on the video wrapper using padding instead of a minimum height corresponding to a vw/vh %.

```css
.videowrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.videowrapper iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.videowrapper-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videowrapper">
            <div class="videowrapper-content">
            <span class="lfg-h1 lfg-h1-ad-2 lfg-text-mobile-hide-2 wow animated fadeInDown delay-1s" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Business Name</span>
            <a href="#" class="hbtn hb-fill-right wow animated fadeInDown delay-1s">Shop the video<i style="padding-left: 7px;" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="hbtn hb-fill-right wow animated fadeInDown delay-1s">Keep watching<i style="padding-left: 7px;" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
         </div>
                   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/355653150?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

          </div>
```